# Cannot find TypeScript custom definition file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

I am trying to create custom definition file for my external JS library. I am receiving the message that `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve`. I am using this project https://github.com/juristr/webpack-typescript-starter.

I wanted to keep my d.ts files in root folder inside custom_typings. The project structure looks like this:

- custom_typing
- - index.d.ts
- node_modules
- src
- - greeter.ts
- webpack.config.js
- tsconfig.json

greeter.ts

```
import * as t from './../custom_typing/index';
export class Greeter {
    constructor(name: string) {
        t.test('dasd');
    }

    greet(): void {
    }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const ROOT = path.resolve( __dirname, 'src' );
const DESTINATION = path.resolve( __dirname, 'dist' );

module.exports = {
    context: ROOT,

    entry: {
        'main': './main.ts'
    },

    output: {
        filename: 'app.bundle.js',
        path: DESTINATION
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
        modules: [
            ROOT,
            'node_modules'
        ]
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            /****************
            * PRE-LOADERS
            *****************/
            {
                enforce: 'pre',
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: 'source-map-loader'
            },
            {
                enforce: 'pre',
                test: /\.ts$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'tslint-loader'
            },

            /****************
            * LOADERS
            *****************/
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                exclude: [ /node_modules/ ],
                use: 'awesome-typescript-loader'
            }
        ]
    },

    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
    devServer: {}
};
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true
  }
}
```

my example of index.d.ts

```
export declare function test(test: string): void;
```

When I run webpack command I get

> ERROR in ./greeter.ts
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './../custom_typing/index'

Edit.

When I renamed index.d.ts to index.ts it seems to work, but I still need to have d.ts file working.

Comment: What happens if you use, instead: `import * as t from '../custom_typing';`? Also, please try: `import * as t from './custom_typing';`. I feel like the webpack config will try to resolve modules from `src` instead, though it should be specified in the tsconfig as well.

Comment: Hi, the problem still occurs

Comment: Can you share your  custom_typing?

Comment: Have a look at `compilerOptions.typeRoots`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html